# Why google is not following material design on gmail?

Tags: material-design, google, gmail

Almost every app in gsuite including google drive, keep, classroom etc. are on material guidelines including the forum but why not Gmail?

Is there a particular reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any proof to back this up. However, Gmail has been around for 13 years. There are probably some people who have been using it for a very long time and don't want to learn a new layout.

In addition, Google has a Material Design email client at [inbox.google.com](https://inbox.google.com).